# flutter align errorText to the bottom-right of textField

Tags: flutter, textfield, flutter-layout

I want to align inputDecoration errorText to the bottom-right of TextField.
The default mode is bottom-left.
I want to set it like

[image: this image]

here is my textField code:

```
TextField authTextFiled(
    String hint, ValidationBloc bloc, AsyncSnapshot<String> snapshot) {
  return TextField(
    textAlign: TextAlign.right,
    onChanged: (String text) => bloc.updateText(text),
    decoration: InputDecoration(
      hintStyle: AppStyle.textFieldHintTextStyle,
      errorStyle: AppStyle.textFieldErrorTextStyle,
      errorText: snapshot.hasError ? snapshot.error : null,
      border: OutlineInputBorder(borderRadius: AppStyle.borderRadius),

      disabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
        borderRadius: AppStyle.borderRadius,
        borderSide: BorderSide(width: 1, color: AppColors.pinkDarkDisableColor)
      ),

      focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
        borderRadius: AppStyle.borderRadius,
        borderSide: BorderSide(width: 1, color: AppColors.bluePrimaryColor),
      ),

      errorBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
          borderRadius: AppStyle.borderRadius,
          borderSide: BorderSide(width: 1, color: AppColors.pinkDarkHotColor)
      ),

      focusedErrorBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
          borderRadius: AppStyle.borderRadius,
          borderSide: BorderSide(width: 1, color: AppColors.pinkDarkHotColor)),
      hintText: hint,
    ),

    keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
    textDirection: TextDirection.rtl,
  );
}
```

any help would be appreciated.

Comment: [related issue](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/11068).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Wrap your `TextFormField` inside `Directionality` and give RTL direction,

```
Directionality(
            textDirection: TextDirection.rtl,
            child: TextFormField(
              ...
```

What is [Directionality CLass](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Directionality-class.html)?

> A widget that determines the ambient directionality of text and text-direction-sensitive render objects.

Output

[image]

Comment: Thank you. Is there any way to have hint text in rtl direction and input text in ltr? exccept of changing Directionality state when textField is empty or not.

Comment: there is a  property called  hintTextDirection: you can set it to what you want